# Remove Port Number from URL Thin Server 1.5 with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, thin

I have a small Rails app currently being served (dev and production) by Thin server on port 3000, on a Debian box that also has apache2 running, serving PHP applications.

I am not certain if this is even possible given the current setup but is there a way to remove the port number from the rails app url but still have Thin listening from the same port so not to bump into apache?

**Current**

```
https://my-rails-site:3000/
```

**Proposed**

```
https://my-rails-site/
```

Or should I just use something like Passenger?

**OR**

mod_proxy?

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove the port number from the URL **and** have your app listening on a non-standard port at the same time? Then you *must* have Apache/Nginx must listen on the standard port and proxy requests to your app's non-standard port. You need to either setup Apache with mod_proxy or Nginx with proxy_module.

If you just want your app to be accessible over a standard port then you can just use [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/), that makes things very easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using passenger here is what I had to use to get it working on www.mysite.com without using www.mysite.com:80 on a centos server:

In etc/httpd/conf the key was to uncomment the NameVirtualHost *:80 and change the * to my server's IP address. Make sure Listen 80 is uncommented. Also add your ip to the VirtualHost tag. It must be running on port 80, not 8080 or something of your choosing.

---

```
NameVirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80  

Listen 80  

<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/public/
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/public/>
       # This relaxes Apache security settings.
       AllowOverride all
       # MultiViews must be turned off.
       Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```